# how do I set week interval dates in flutter, like January 3,2019, January 10, 2019, January 17,2019 for 3 months?

Tags: flutter

how do I generate week interval dates in flutter, like January 3,2019, January 10, 2019, January 17,2019  for 3  months?

```
*This is my code*
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Repayment Schedule'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: getListView('Total Payment', 'Ghs 100'),
    );
  }
}

List<String> getDateElement() {

  var _startingDate = DateTime.now();

  DateTime _newDate = _startingDate.add(Duration(days: 7));
  var dates = List<String>.generate(24,(counter)=> "$_newDate");
  return dates;
}



List<String> getListElement() {

  var item = List<String>.generate(24, (counter)=> "Week $counter");
  return item;
}

Widget getListView( String totalPmt, String amount,) {

  var listItems = getListElement();
  var listDates = getDateElement();

  var listView = ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listItems.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {

      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Text(listItems[index]),
          title: new Text(totalPmt),
          subtitle: Text(amount),
          trailing: Text(listDates[index]),
        ),
      );
    }
  );

  return listView;
}
```

I want something like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAeIr.png),
I'm getting this instead [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urOOE.jpg)

how do I get the first result, thank you. I have been trying this for sometime now. i am new to flutter.

Comment: Would you like to display the week view or something else? OR please share the image exactly what you want to display.

Comment: Please image one is what I'm trying to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using `counter` in your generator to advance the date. Try:

```
 List<String> getDates() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  return List.generate(
      24, (counter) => now.add(Duration(days: counter * 7)).toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. sorry for the late response.. it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime _newDate = _startingDate.add(Duration(days: 7));
```

then just loop that til you hit your max date.